# Why Wordpress Cache plugin does't work with NGINX/PHP-FM?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Centos7, Vestacp, Nginx/PHP-FM, WordPress Multisite on subdomains.

All work fine, but my Caching plugins don't work.
I try wp-super-cache, Now i use Cache-Enabler plugin.
But does not work... two days can't relsove this problem. Please help.

Part of my nginx template

```
# CacheEnabler Start
 set $cache_uri $request_uri;

# bypass cache if POST requests or URLs with a query string
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $cache_uri 'nullcache';
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $cache_uri 'nullcache';
}

# bypass cache if URLs containing the following strings
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
    set $cache_uri 'nullcache';
}

# bypass cache if the cookies containing the following strings
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $cache_uri 'nullcache';
}
# default html file
set $cache_enabler_uri '/wp-content/cache/cache-enabler/${http_host}${cache_uri}index.html';    

location / {
try_files $cache_enabler_uri $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;   

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    %backend_lsnr%;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   %home%/%user%/web/%domain%/document_errors/;
}
include     %home%/%user%/conf/web/nginx.%domain_idn%.conf*;
```

Comment: Part of my nginx.conf
`open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/fcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;`

Answer (score 0):

I try **Breeze plugin**, and this is work right after install.

WpSupercache, cache enabler, litespeed, does't work (multisite, subdomains, nginx+php-fpm)